# Laravel 5.2 redirect in AuthController create method

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to redirect user to the homepage if hidden input field has been changed to an invalid value, but since create method must return user instance i can't do that here. So what are my options?

```
 /**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $role = Role::where('name', $data['role'])->first();

    // Hidden role field has been tampered with! Redirect to homepage.
    if(!$role){
        return redirect('/');
    }

    $user = new User();
    $user->email = $data['email'];
    $user->password = bcrypt($data['password']);
    $user->save();
    $user->roles()->attach($role);
    return $user;
}
```

Fatal error with above code:

```
FatalThrowableError in SessionGuard.php line 418:
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse given, called in E:\xampp\htdocs\taskie\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php on line 63
```

Comment: Explain your problem specifically.If you get any error then show it and tell what you want?

Comment: @Chonchol Mahmud Updated initial question with error message. I want to redirect user to homepage from within the create() method if hidden input field does not contain a valid value.

Comment: Show your routes file for homepage.

Comment: Actually, this is not a controller method. The `redirect()` function returns a `Response` object and are meant to be returned only from inside controllers (or anonymous functions declared with routes). Therefore, you should look at the controller handling the request. Is it the  `AuthController` generated with `artisan make:auth`?

Answer (score 0):

In the `AuthController` generated with artisan `make:auth`, the register user request is handled by the method `register`, not `create`. This method is implemented in the trait `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers`. You may overload this method in your controller and change its behaviour.

```
/**
 * Handle a registration request for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $role = Role::where('name', $data['role'])->first();

    // Hidden role field has been tampered with! Redirect to homepage.
    if(!$role){
        return redirect('/');
    }

    return parent::register($response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating a custom validation.

```
'email' => ['required','max:255','unique:users','regex:/(@org.co.uk)$/',],
```

and now no need of Redirects.